# How to handle the JSON formatted string?

Tags: python, json, web.py

I use json.dumps() to handle the value and want to display them in the front-end.

I set the header to "application/json",but it doesn't work well and the quote is converted to `&quot;` in the browser.

How do I convert them to the normal output like {"key": "value"} rather than 
`{&quot;key&quot;: &quot;value&quot;}`?

This is my [url](http://southmoneyweixin.sinaapp.com/callback?callback=sof).I use web.py to handle the data.

```
import json
import os
import urllib2
import web

app_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
templates_root = os.path.join(app_root, 'templates')
render = web.template.render(templates_root)

class Callback:
    def GET(self):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
        url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/hot.json"
        hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'super happy flair bot by /u/spladug' }
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        html = json.dumps(html)  
        func_name = web.input()['callback']
        html = '{0}({1})'.format(func_name, html)
        return render.callback(html)
```

Comment: What web framework are you using? It's probably automatically escaping your output and you need to mark it as "safe".

Comment: Your web  framework is escaping the output. What framework are you using?

Comment: @FogleBird I use webpy.

Comment: @LieRyan I use webpy.

Comment: Are you using a template? Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513446/webpy-how-to-serve-json

Comment: @FogleBird I update my question.Can you have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return render.callback(html)` to `return html` - no need for the template engine here.

Also, you might consider using the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module instead of urllib2. It's much nicer.

Comment: Thx,but the quote has a backslash prefix now.